# Difference between hideous, odious and obnoxious

Tags: meaning, word-choice, connotation

I wonder about the difference between 'hideous', 'odious' and 'obnoxious'

All three of them share the following definition at oxforddictionaries.com

> Extremely unpleasant

While I know that 'hideous' is often used to describe a visually ugly thing, I do not fathom what the subtle dissimilarities of these terms are when it comes to describing unpleasantness.

Note that I am a non-native speaker.

Comment: What does the dictionary tell you, beyond "extremely unpleasant"? If nothing, try another dictionary. Oh, and what you cite is **not** what I see at the site cited (oxforddictionaries.com).

Answer (score 4):

**Hideous** is typically used in the context of physical appearance. An extremely unattractive, or ugly person may be called "hideous".

**Odious** is typically used in the context of personality, and relates to "hate". It comes from the Latin word, "odium", which means "to hate".

**Obnoxious** is also typically used in context of personality, but reflects more annoyance than hate. A person with a bad habit, or unpleasant personality may be *obnoxious*, but you may not find them to be *odious*.

Comment: Hideous is rarely used in the US, and sounds effeminate and shrill to our ears. We say ugly. But the British use it. That Hideous Strength, a novel by C.S. Lewis.  But Americans do say odious and obnoxious. Odious debt; an obnoxious personality.

Comment: As an native-English speaking American, I'll go ahead and disagree with you, but you're welcome to your opinion, of course.

Comment: @phantom42 Easy to misread as an English-speaking Native American ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at the [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/) to find some clues. The words came from different sources, and the current nuances seem to be based to some extent on their original meanings.

(my approximate synonyms, with extracts from etymonline.com)

- hideous - *horrifying*

  > from Anglo-French hidous, Old French hideus, earlier hisdos "hideous, horrible, awful, frightening" (11c.; Modern French hideux), from hisda "horror, fear," perhaps of Germanic origin.
- odious - *hateful or offensive*

  > from Old French odieus (late 14c., Modern French odieux) or directly from Latin odiosus "hateful, offensive, unpleasant," from odium "hatred"
- obnoxious - *harmful*

  > from Latin obnoxiosus "hurtful, injurious," from obnoxius "subject, exposed to harm," from ob "to, toward" (see ob-) + noxa "injury, hurt, damage entailing liability"

Hopefully this gives you some idea about which to use depending on the type of 'unpleasantness' you're describing.